# Oracle: Finding the database schema size without accessing dba_data_files

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I don't have access to `dba_segments` or `dba_data_files` in `Oracle database`. However, I have access to `user_segments`.

Is there anyway I can find the total size of a database schema in an Oracle database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Connect to the schema and sum the bytes from `USER_SEGMENTS`.

```
SQL> conn user
Password:
Connected.

SQL> select sum(bytes) from user_segments;

SUM(BYTES)
----------
    524288
```